# Kernel panic invasion on Mac G5

Tags: mac, kernel-panic, g5

I found my old Mac G5 with Tiger and started it, but forgot the password. Then I tried to crack it using the single-user mode. But then, after I start it, mostly every time, there is a kernel panic. How do I fix it? What do I need to reset? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @sheva ! Please add the kernel panic report to the question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: Were you successful in your crack?  What did you do exactly?  Did the kernel panics only start after you attempted to crack the password?  Do you have the original (Tiger) recovery/installation disks?